# Extending a DOM element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to extend a DOM element without extending all of them. That is, I'd like a custom class with its own methods and properties, but also be able to treat it as a div. E.g.

```
 MyClass = function(){
    this.foo = "waaa";
 }
 MyClass.prototype.changeText = function(newtext){
    // if this extended $(document.createElement("div")) something
    // like this might be possible
    this.html(newtext);
 }
 MyClass.prototype.alertFoo = function(){
    alert(this.foo);
 }

 var m = new MyClass();
 $("body").append(m);
 m.changetext();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your class a child class of the jquery generated DIV element:

```
function MyClass (){
    this.foo = "waaa";
}
MyClass.prototype = $('<div/>');
MyClass.prototype.changeText = function(newtext){
    this.html(newtext);
}
MyClass.prototype.alertFoo = function(){
    alert(this.foo);
}

var m = new MyClass();
$("body").append(m);
m.changeText('appletree');
```

Comment: This works great for extending plugins too, overriding functions so that this.hide is actually this.fadeOut. I use __proto__ inside the class and pass it the base jquery object like this: [link](http://pastebin.com/hFUnqTBQ)

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own object, like you are doing. Then you can use jQuery's [extend method](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.extend) to extend the element.

Comment: This doesn't work:

function more(){
    this.myname = "more!"
   }
   more.prototype.alert = function(){
    alert('alert!')
   }
   
   var div = $(document.createElement("div"));
   div.html("this is s");
   
   $.extend(true, div, more);
   
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").append(div);
    div.alert();
    alert(div.myname);
   });

Comment: right, you need an object, not a function for it to work with the `extend` method. replace the appropriate line with this: `$.extend(true, div, new more);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem will come when you want to retrieve the element later.  Maybe you can just store the extensions as data of the element like such:

```
var new_div = $('<div id="new_div" />');
new_div.data('m', new MyClass());
```

Then to call the functions later, you would do something like:

```
new_div.data('m').changetext(new_div)
```

And pass the div as an argument.

Comment: Yeah, I realize something like this is possible, but it's certainly not elegant. For all the hype about javascript being so great, the fact that I can't make my custom class walk like a jquery duck kinda sucks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it as a plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.myKindOfElement = function(msg) {
    var foo = msg; // foo is basically a private member
    this.alertFoo = function() {
        alert(foo);
    };
    this.setFoo = function(msg) {
        foo = msg;
    };
    this.changeText = function(text) {
        // doesn't make sense because html already exists here
        this.html(text);
    };
};
```

Then for any element:

```
var myKind = $('<div/>').myKindOfElement('bar');
$('body').append(myKind);
myKind.alertFoo(); // alerts 'bar'
myKind.changeText('blah'); // same as myKind.html('blah')
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery won't be able to understand m when you pass it to the append line, because it only accepts strings and elements. Your MyClass will probably have a specific key to hold the element itself (e.g. this.el = document.createElement("div");), but jQuery won't be able to find that on its own.

Comment: Understood, the above was just an example of what I was looking to do. In essence I'm looking for something like:

MyClass : document.createElement("div")

That is, I don't want to tell jquery to find the specific key, but have jquery think the object itself is the element, i.e. my object extends the element.